# "IllegalArgumentException occurred while calling setter for property" from sqlserver numeric to java object

Tags: java, sql-server, hibernate

I already have such an error, when you try to perform unapropriate matching (date to boolean, and so) which I had been able to fix quite easilly.

But this time, I am quite confused, because hibernate refuses to match a "numeric" Id to a Java "Long" (and it also failed when setter is made for Double, Integer, Float, String, int, long, etc.)

The sql-server field "id" is a *NUMERIC(19,0)*

**My DTO is :**

```
@XmlRootElement
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.PROPERTY)
public class DtoResult {

private Long id;
private String name;
// ...


public Long getId() {
    return id;
}
public void setId(final Long id) {
    this.id = id;
}   
public String getName() {
    return name;
}
public void setName(final String name) {
    this.name = name;
}
}
```

My hibernate query :

```
    final SQLQuery query= getCurrentSession().createSQLQuery(select + from + where);

    query.setParameter("manyFields", manyFields);
        query
        .addScalar("id")
        .addScalar("name")
        .setResultTransformer(Transformers.aliasToBean(DtoResult.class));

    return query.list(); // List<DtoResult>
```

**Error:**

```
IllegalArgumentException  occurred while calling setter for property [com.some.thing.DtoResult.id (expected type = java.lang.Long)]; target = [com.some.thing.DtoResult@77a70b79], property value = [269895]
```

I am really puzzled about this, thus any help is welcome.

Thanks for reading untill there.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Just add the expected type, like:

```
    .addScalar("id", new LongType())
    .addScalar("name", new StringType())
```

Comment: That did the trick : great and thanks a lot. Though, I am not sure to undestand ; I did such a query many times, without adding the "type". Why do I have to specify it now? One of the requested tables is actuallty a VIEW. May it be the cause?

Answer (score 1):

The number from database query is not Long but BigInteger.

Change setter to:

```
public void setId(final Number id) {
    this.id = id != null ? id.longValue() : null;
}
```